# InputStream converting punctuation to Unicode

Tags: java, android, html, unicode, android-asynctask

My app connects to the internet and scrubs a page to get the html to get things like the image and the text. However I have noticed that some punctuation actually gets converted to its unicode decimal code, anyway to stop this?

```
public class DownloadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public interface PageResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }

    private PageResponse delegate = null;

    public DownloadPage(PageResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URLConnection connection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            connection = url.openConnection();

            String html;
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            html = str.toString();

            return html;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        delegate.processFinish(s);
    }
}
```

This is the page I am getting the information from, https://www.looemusic.co.uk/news/ .

[This is what comes up with this code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6yGI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the problem is with your InputStream, and not the HTML rendering itself, then you could set your InputStreamReader's Charset:

```
new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.UTF-8);
```

This Charset is from Java.nio.charset.

If this fails, you could check out if the problem is not with your client's encoding. Put this tag at your HTML file:

For HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

For HTML 4:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

If you want to use another charset instead of UTF-8 then just change the names in the code!

Comment: It doesn't like the Charset.UTF-8 . It isn't an option